# run and debug have different results in method named append() in StringBuffer

Tags: java, debugging, debuggervisualizer

[image: StringBufferTest]

In picture's code ,I will get the different result.

The first case, run the code,print is 111222.

The second case, debug the code，print is 111.

[image: StringBuffer]

And also I find a problem in source code.

From the picture above we could find the Expression `toStringCache = null` execute is not success.

Please tell me the reason about this problem.

Thanks.

## **run print**

[image: result1]
**

## **debug print**

[image: result2]

PS:In jdk7,It hasn't `toStringCache` attribute the results are same.
But, in jdk8 or more higher edition the results are different.

Comment: You are debugging in two different places - why are you stepping into `StringBuilder::append` ?

Comment: I stepping into StringBuilder::append?  Isn't StringBuffer::append?

Comment: Sorry, `StringBuffer` - BTW this is deprecated isn't it

Comment: @ScaryWombat Not exactly, it is just preferred that `StringBuilder` is used. The JavaDoc states that `StringBuilder` will be faster when using a single thread since it does not use synchronization.

Comment: Yeah,but I want to know why results are different

Comment: You have not shown proof that the results are different.

Comment: results are same in both cases

Comment: The result have been supplemented.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I found the problem caused by Intelij IDEA.The code run in Eclipse have same print.
What's wrong?

When `StringBuffer's` instance changed ,Its private arttribute `toStringCache` will be assigned to null.

But in Intelij IDEA,it will not be assigned to null.（But,up to now I don't know the reason,maybe it is a bug.）

And when we print s,it will call method `toString()`,it will check whether `toStringCache` is null. If `toStringCache` is null,will generate a new value from parent Class private attribute `value`.And then return `toStringCache` .

Here is Source code about `append(String str)`,`toString()` in `StringBuffer`

```
  @Override
    @HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate
    public synchronized StringBuffer append(String str) {
        toStringCache = null;
        super.append(str);
        return this;
    }

 @Override
    @HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate
    public synchronized String toString() {
        if (toStringCache == null) {
            return toStringCache =
                    isLatin1() ? StringLatin1.newString(value, 0, count)
                               : StringUTF16.newString(value, 0, count);
        }
        return new String(toStringCache);
    }
```